Proteger panel admin en proyecto SLIM V4
Tengo un proyecto slim que consta de la siguiente estructura:
public
   assets
   templates
   .htaccess
   index.php
routes
 (fichero que habilita las distintas rutas de mi proyecto)
src
  templates
    admin
     ( distintos ficheros que usaría para mostrar el admin)
vendor
.htpasswd

Ahora cómo protejo mediante .htaccess mi panel de administración?
He probado a crear un .htaccess dentro de src\templates\admin\.htaccess y que lea el fichero .htpasswd que está en la raíz del proyecto.
Pero por más que lo configure, accedo y no pide usuario/contraseña.
Las rutas están correctas pero entiendo que no estoy situando bien el fichero .htaccess ni configurándolo bien.
¿alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Te explico paso por paso cómo lo tengo configurado.

En una carpeta oculta del directorio raíz, asumiendo que dicho directorio es home y esa carpeta se llama .micarpetapasswd creamos el archivo .htpasswd poniendo el nombre de usuario seguido de dos puntos y luego la contraseña, la cual conviene que esté encriptada, ver aquí para generar una contraseña encriptada. El contenido en home/.micarpetapasswd/.htpasswd será algo parecido a esto:
elUsuario:$apr1$vs4jpx5w$QHvWEJpeANvVOOjBO59F/.


En src\templates\admin\.htaccess indicas que admin es una carpeta protegida por contraseña poniendo lo siguiente:
 authType Basic
 AuthName "privado"
 AuthUserFile /home/.micarpetapasswds/.htpasswd
 require valid-user
 ErrorDocument 401 "Authorisation Required"



Con ambas cosas, debería pedirte el nombre de usuario y la contraseña cada vez que intentes acceder a admin. Recuerda que no debes poner la contraseña encriptada, sino la que usaste la primera vez al generar el password encriptado. Si sigue sin funcionar, entonces verifica que todas las rutas son correctas.
En mi caso estoy en hosting compartido, y no tengo acceso de administrador, si lo tuvieras, es mejor hacer la configuración siguiendo las instrucciones de Apache.

Hola @a-cedano gracias por tu ayuda!
Mi problema en sí es que creo que la estructura no doy con ella...los documentos en sí están bien (tanto htaccess como htpasswd) pero no consigo para slim que salte. No sé si la carpeta admin tengo que tenerla dentro de mi /public/ o cómo hacerlo para que me requiera el .htaccess
